# Will HikariCP auto Shut Poll when Program Exit

Tags: hikaricp

Should I shut down the data source mannully when my program exits? If it is, then what is the best practice to close the source, for example, if the `kill` cmd is issued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shutdown()` or `close()` is essential at application termination, otherwise you will leave database resources in use.

Solution found in [old issue](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/210) to call `close` on your `DataSource`:

> you can simply cast to Closeable and call close